# Apache Camel Issue having routingSlip after a filter

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am in the process of implementing a Camel route in which I need to put a filter before redirecting the message processing to an end point or another depending of a `routing slip` header. Something like below:

```
        from("direct:a")
            .routeId("a")
            .choice()
                .when(header("foo"))
                    .filter(body().isNotNull())
                    .routingSlip(header("my-slip"))
                .endChoice()
                .otherwise()
                    .log("header 'foo' was false")
                .endChoice()
            .end();
```

When trying to run the application I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.camel.model.FilterDefinition cannot be cast to class org.apache.camel.model.ChoiceDefinition
```

Any explanation why this is not a legal construct and how should I code my route to achieve what I want. From my own observations it is the `choice()` construct that is causing this. Adding a `routingSlip` construct after a `filter` works just fine if the choice is not there.

Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `.end()` after `.routingSlip(header("my-slip"))` to close the filter definition.

```java
 from("direct:a")
.routeId("a")
.choice()
    .when(header("foo"))
        .filter(body().isNotNull())
            .routingSlip(header("my-slip"))
        .end()
    .endChoice()
    .otherwise()
        .log("header 'foo' was false")
    .endChoice()
.end();
```

Comment: I created a unit test and it worked exactly as expected. I did not know you might need to end a filter but it is good when u learn something new.

Comment: Filter is basically the same as `if` without the `else` so you can add a bunch of routing logic in it. One common way I use it is to early out the route in cases like when database query result contains 0 entries or REST-API request is missing required parameters or something.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `filter`. Put all the conditions in the `when`branch.
For example, here I am using the Simple language:

```
from("direct:a")
.routeId("a")
.choice()
    .when(simple("${header.foo} !=null and ${body}!=null))
        .routingSlip(header("my-slip"))
    .endChoice()
    .otherwise()
        .log("header 'foo' was false")
    .endChoice()
.end();
```

`filter` and `choice` are similar. You can use `filter` instead of a single `if` (or also to filter items from a list); use `choice` instead in case of an `if .. else`.

Comment: Alternative to simple in this case would be to use `and` from [compound predicates](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/predicate.html#Predicate-CompoundPredicates) (`import static org.apache.camel.builder.PredicateBuilder.and`).

Comment: This will not work because if body is null it will end up executing `otherwise` branch which is not what I want. Not important to my issue but `${header.foo} != null` is also not correct because foo is a boolean. It should be just  `${header.foo}`